# how convert this pine code script to version 4?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

how convert the code or point me at the right direction? i get an undeclared identifier error with it,

here a photo of the errors

[image]

sharing code. will appreciate if anyone can convert it to a version 4 pine script

```
study(title="SLSE", shorttitle="brez", overlay=true, precision=3)
src=input(hl2, title="Source")
a= input(0.07, title="Alpha", step=0.01) 
fr=input(false, title="Fill Trend Region")
ebc=input(false, title="Enable barcolors")
hr=input(false, title="Hide Ribbon")
it=(a-((a*a)/4.0))*src+0.5*a*a*src[1]-(a-0.75*a*a)*src[2]+2*(1-a )*nz(it[1], ((src+2*src[1]+src[2])/4.0))-(1-a )*(1-a )*nz(it[2], ((src+2*src[1]+src[2])/4.0))
lag=2.0*it-nz(it[2])
dl=plot(fr and (not hr)?(it>lag?lag:it):na, color=gray, style=circles, linewidth=0, title="Dummy")
itl=plot(hr?na:it, color=fr?gray:red, linewidth=1, title="Trend")
ll=plot(hr?na:lag, color=fr?gray:blue, linewidth=1, title="Trigger")
fill(dl, ll, green, title="UpTrend", transp=70)
fill(dl, itl, red, title="DownTrend", transp=70)
bc=not ebc?na:(it>lag?red:lime)
barcolor(bc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Version 4.0 requires you to use `color.{insert_color_name}`. So change all your colors, prepend this to your colors. Also the reason it has errors, is because you're accessing it before being declared. The "circles" must be modified to `plot.style_circles`.

It'd be very handy for you to visit https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/

Comment: thanks man helped alot. figuring out now how i should declare "it, lag, bc, dl"